# linux capabilities - iptables as child process

Tags: linux, linux-capabilities

I have a process that fork-execlp "iptables-restore file.rules". It looks like it doesn't have the permission since I don't see some of the rules not listed like INPUT DROP after the process executes. When I run this process as a root, it seems to be fine but not when I run as a user with following capabilities:

```
parent process - cap_kill,cap_net_bind_service,cap_net_broadcast,cap_net_admin,cap_net_raw+ei
child ( iptables-restore ) - cap_net_admin,cap_net_raw+ei
```

What is the capability that I am missing?

Comment: that is not true. regular joe user can do, if the process have appropriate linux capability ( sudoers is one way but it lacks granularity ). look up linux capabilities it is a better way. The question here what happened to its capabilities after you exec even though you made it in heritable.

Comment: yes. and I said suders is not the only way.

Answer (score 0):

I just got the same issue. My suspicion is that the issue is not about capabilities, but about simple filesystem permissions. The error I see is:

```bash
Fatal: can't open lock file /run/xtables.lock: Permission denied
```

The file is owned by root:root, and is RW only by the owner. So either change the file ownership to a group and `chmod g+rw` or use an alternative lock location using The XTABLES_LOCKFILE environment variable (based on iptables manual).
If anyone has a different solution I would love to hear about it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).